# How do I trigger an event in the setter of a property?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, event-handling, delegates

I have a property by the name "TrendPoint" of type ITrendPoint. I need to raise a "OnTrendPointChanged" event whenever the value of the TrendPoint changes and perform a set of operations.
I've tried the following but can't seem to proceed further:

```
  public class TestClass:ObservablePoint
  {

    private ITrendPoint trendPoint;

    public ITrendPoint TrendPoint{
        get{ return trendPoint ;}
        set{ this.trendPoint= value;
       //Need to Call the event handler 
       // "OnTrendPointChanged"
        }


     public void TestJob()
      {
        //The TrendPoint is being set 
         // here
          TrendPoint= 
       Services.getTrendPoint();

      }



         //The event handler
     private void 
     OnTrendPointChanged(object sender, 
     ValueChangedEventArgs<string> e)
     {
        switch(e.value):
         case "HIGH":
         Log("TR HIGH");
         case "Low":
         Log("TR LOW");
       //Other such conditions
       .
       .
       .
 
      }

}
```

I'm not able to figure out how exactly do I get the eventhandler "OnTrendPointChanged" to execute whenever the value of "TrendPoint" changes. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You really want the event handler in the same class? Doesn't make sense to me. You could as well just call the method from the setter.

Comment: Or do you want something like this: [How to: Implement the INotifyPropertyChanged Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/how-to-implement-the-inotifypropertychanged-interface?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) or [IObservable<T> Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iobservable-1?view=net-6.0)

Comment: Is your question actually how do you build an eventargs with the new value?

Comment: @Fildor Thank you for the link you provided.

Comment: @Andy seems like I've got the entire code snippet wrong. My goal is to be able to perform a set of operations whenever the value of the TrentPoint changes.

Comment: @Fildor yes, that seems absurd to me now that I see how the EventHandler can directly be called from within the getter. What about the parameters "sender" and "e"? What should I pass into it? Note :EventHandler code snippet was shared to me and my goal was to perform the operation in the EventHandler whenever the TrendPoint property value changes. I'm super confused now:(

Comment: Have you even tried compiling that code?  Eventargs is a class. You could look it up on msdn if you searched.  Take a look now. See any value property?

Comment: @Andy My bad! I had mistyped the ValueChangedEventArgs as EventArgs. I've edited the code now. Yes I looked up the EventArgs class and no it doesn't have any value property.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear that there is any point to having an eventhandler in your code at all.

Setting that aside. You don't seem to use sender so that can be null.  Maybe you have some code uses that which you're not showing us. In which case you need to pass some instance of whatever sender is going to be in.  This is not clear from what you've provided ( naughty ).

So we can pass null, for sender but need a valuechangedeventargs instance to pass.

Something like:

```
public ITrendPoint TrendPoint{
    get{ return trendPoint ;}
    set{ this.trendPoint= value;
        var vc = new ValueChangedEventArgs<TrendPoint>(this.trendPoint);
        OnTrendPointChanged(null, vc);
    }
```

Assuming OnTrendPointChanged is in the same class. Seems to be from what you've provided but maybe it isn't.

If the handler is in some other class then you will need to reference an instance of that, obviously.

How did I know a valuechangedeventargs works like that?  I looked it up:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.language.intellisense.valuechangedeventargs-1?view=visualstudiosdk-2022

Hope all this helps.